# SQLAlchemy / WTForms QuerySelectField

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyramid, wtforms

I am attempting to use WTForms with the SQLAlchemy extension on a Pyramid application.

I have done:

```
from wtforms import Form, TextField,TextAreaField, validators
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
from app.models import DBSession
from app.models import ParentModel


class NewChild(Form):
    title = TextField('Title:', [validators.Required()])
    intro = TextAreaField('Introduction:')
    body = TextAreaField('Body:')
    parent = QuerySelectField(query_factory=DBSession().query(ParentModel).all)
```

DBSession is defined as

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
```

The query seems to work, but the display in my template is reading

```
<app.models.ParentModel object at 0x9xxx>
```

or some such. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is ParentModel a Class? maybe you should try ParentModel.name or something you want display

Comment: I tried... in fact, I have a class method `DBSession.query(ParentModel).order_by(sa.desc(ParentModel.title))` that displays the titles when called as a direct variable in a template (i.e. `variable = ParentModel.all()`). This doesn't change the output I'm seeing on the form though.

Comment: Can you show us your Template Form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a a `__str__` method on `ParentModel`

Comment: dear @javex can you please state how to define  `__str__` method on ParentModel??

Comment: @Max I am honestly not sure what you mean? You go where `class ParentModel` can be found and inside its block you do `def __str__(self):`. This is basic python. Otherwise I don't get your question.

Comment: oh I get it, sorry for taking your time :(